# MySQL - creating more results than one starts with (example: integers within an interval)

Tags: mysql, sql

I could fall back to a procedure with a while loop (maybe, I've never tried to do this before) but there must be a faster way.

[backspaced stuff - I'll just show describes]

```
CREATE TABLE  `table` (
  `ZoneId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `VolumeId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `TypeId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ExtraTypeInfo` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `StartIndex` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `EndIndex` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `SectionId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ZoneId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`StartIndex` and `EndIndex` denote a range, it is saying everything from start until the end has the properties this record describes (say a range covers 300,000 this is better than 300,000 rows, also the items don't need IDs, their position is their ID)

Some indices will be covered twice, for example the range `[1,20]` and `[1,1]` with `TypeId` 0 means that `1` has been (whatever it denotes) twice, and 2-20 inclusive just once, the rest 0 times.

Rather than reading the table and keeping a manual tally I'd rather shift the work to MySQL, I (sadly) must use PHP and it uses too much memory if I use an array or object per entry, and takes too long if I use a bitfield.

Rather than being tossed a query and using it I'd rather learn how to do this, so I would love a solution has three columns:

```
section | index | count0 | count1
```

Where count0 is the number of times intervals with `TypeId` 0 has covered the index, and `count1` where it is 1. I have asked for both to prevent solutions where this'd be done as two queries. (In the field this will be subject to a given VolumeId)

The length of a section is of course known

### Example

Suppose we have (ignoring `ZoneId`,`ExtraTypeInfo` and `Time` for simplicity) with this dataset:

```
VolId TypeId Start End Section
1     0      1     2   1
1     0      2     2   1
2     0      1     1   1
1     1      2     3   1
1     0      1     2   2
```

To output (subject to VolId = 1)

```
sec ind c0 c1
1   1   1  0
1   2   2  1
1   3   1  1
1   4   0  0  <--notice this, we do know the length of sec 1 and 4 was covered by nothing
2   1   1  0
2   2   1  0
2   3   0  0
2   4   0  0
2   5   0  0
```

Indices may start at 0 or 1, it is easy to change and as yet undecided (starting at 1 is most natural for the application, 0 helps only with the code)

I hope SQL can do this. I will carry on reading but I'm not sure what to do, as I mentioned at the top I am thinking of a procedure that runs over all sections that calls a procedure to generate lists from 1 to length, and then searching for each of those and hoping MySQL's optimiser spots what is going on.

Comment: You do realise "optimise" is with an s. In British English we do not overuse the letter "z". Seriously guys, this is like removing the "u" from "colour". You do not say "optimise" with the "zz" sound found at the end of "buzz" (like what a bee might do) at the end, it is softer. `/rant` (this happens a lot)

Comment: There's a whole forum for that kind of stuff guys:  http://english.stackexchange.com/  Let's stay on topic, shall we?  :)

Comment: @eggyal I did not know that, I was taught "ise" and that "ize" was an American thing (like claiming the "h" is silent in "herb"), this changes things and I don't know enough to commit to changing. Thanks for that! Now yes, back on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Further to our [conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49182/chat-between-eggyal-and-alec-teal), I suggest that you create a permanent `number_table` that contains every *possible* index value:

```
CREATE TABLE number_table (ind SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY)
SELECT bF.v|bE.v|bD.v|bC.v|bB.v|bA.v|b9.v|b8.v
      |b7.v|b6.v|b5.v|b4.v|b3.v|b2.v|b1.v|b0.v ind
FROM
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x0) b0,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x1) b1,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x2) b2,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x3) b3,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x4) b4,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x5) b5,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x6) b6,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x7) b7,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x8) b8,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0x9) b9,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0xA) bA,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0xB) bB,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0xC) bC,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0xD) bD,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0xE) bE,
  (SELECT 0 v UNION ALL SELECT 1<<0xF) bF;
   
DELETE FROM number_table WHERE ind = 0;
```

Then you can make an [outer join](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) between this table and your `table` above, limiting the results by the maximum length of the relevant section:

```
SELECT      s.SectionId,
            nt.ind,
            IFNULL(SUM(t.TypeID=0),0) c0,
            IFNULL(SUM(t.TypeID=1),0) c1
FROM        sections s
       JOIN number_table nt
         ON nt.ind <= s.Length
  LEFT JOIN `table` t
         ON t.SectionId = s.SectionId
        AND nt.ind BETWEEN t.StartIndex AND t.EndIndex
        AND t.VolumeId = 1
GROUP BY    s.SectionId, nt.ind
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a3ab/1/0).

Comment: Can you create a permanent link to that convo, thank you ever so much. I know 10 rep isn't much...

Comment: @AlecTeal: The link is in my answer, above.